# How can I create an array of objects in postgres with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

My idea is to define a message model that has 'id' and 'message' attributes, the 'message' attribute will be an array of objects.

Example: `[{from, to, msg, time}]` with their values respectively.

This is how I defined the model:

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../config/database.js';

const MessageSchema = sequelize.define('messages', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    message: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSONB)
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});

export default MessageSchema;
```

when I run the app I get this:
`column "message" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb[]`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

The error you encountered says us that pgSQL database you're using is unable to automatically convert the "message" column to the JSONB array type.

One possible solution is to explicitly define the column type as JSONB array by using the "type" option with the "DataTypes.ARRAY" method.

Please try with this code below.

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../config/database.js';

const MessageSchema = sequelize.define('messages', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    message: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSONB),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: []
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});

export default MessageSchema;
```

I added "allowNull: false" to ensure that "message" column is always required, and "defaultValue: []" to set an empty array as the default value.

I hope this update would help you.